# Finding the map of an angle to the upper half plane

Tags: complex-analysis

How do you find a map from the angle $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\pi/6<\arg(z)< \pi/2\}$ to the upper half-plane? Is this the same as finding what values $z$ can take in the complex plane, and is just a wedge?

And in general, how do you approach problems like this? I know that if it was instead not to the upper half plane and something like $z\mapsto\frac{1}{z}$, we could just say the map is then  $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:0>\arg(z)>-\frac{\pi}{3}\}$ ... correct?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Presumably, you want this map to be “nice” in some sense? Holomorphic?

Comment: Not sure what you mean but probaly? I guess my line of reasoning was to rotate it by -pi/6 first and then doing z->z^3 on this rotation, but im not sure if that is the right way or how I would express it. Would it just be something like e^(-i* pi/6)z^3 or smth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to stretch out this wedge of (angular) width $\frac\pi2 - \frac\pi6 = \frac\pi3$ to the entire half-plane, of width $\pi$, which is an expansion by a factor of $3$. But you also want to turn about the origin so that the arguments land between $0$ and $\pi$.

To stretch the argument by a factor of $3$, use $z \mapsto z^3$. Then to shift the argument (rotate in the complex plane) back to the upper half-plane, multiply by $e^{-i\pi/2} = -i$. Composing these two operations yields the function
$$
f(z) = -iz^3. 
$$

You can check that for any $z = r e^{i\theta}$ in polar form,
$$
f(r e^{i\theta}) = -i\,(r e^{i\theta})^3 
= r^3 e^{i(3\theta - \pi/2)}, 
$$
and that $\theta \mapsto 3\theta - \pi/2$ maps the interval $(\pi/6, \pi/2)$ bijectively onto $(0, \pi)$.

---

You can generalize this result. To map the wedge
$$ 
D(\alpha, \beta) 
= \{ z = re^{i\theta} \in \mathbb{C} \mid r>0 \text{ and } \alpha < \theta < \beta \}
$$
bijectively onto the upper half-plane $H = D(0, \pi)$, you have to determine the appropriate stretch factor and shift for the arguments, i.e. the appropriate affine linear $\theta \mapsto m \theta + c$ sending the interval $(\alpha, \beta)$ to $(0, \pi)$. The function
$$
\theta \mapsto \frac{\pi\, (\theta - \alpha)}{\beta - \alpha}
$$
works, provided that $0 < \beta - \alpha < 2\pi$. You can construct the bijective map $D(\alpha, \beta) \to H$ from this.